# Prove by induction $a-b|a^{n}-b^{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb N$

Tags: induction, divisibility

$P(1)$: $a-b|a-b$

$P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$:

$a-b|a^{n}-b^{n}\Rightarrow a-b|a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The *basis step* (i.e.$P(1)$) is Ok. For the *induction step* you must write $a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}$ as $(a^n-b^n) \times ...$ and then useg the *induction hypotheses*, i.e. the assumption that $a-b|a^n-b^n$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: $$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=(a^{n+1}-ba^n)+(ba^n-b^{n+1})$$

Comment: Ah, so you get $a−b|a^{n}*(a-b) + b*(a^n - b^n)$
Then $a-b|a^n*(a-b)$ is true and $a-b|b*(a^n - b^n)$ is true therefore $P(n+1)$ is valid. Is this correct?

Comment: **Remark** $\ $ This is a special case of the Congruence Product Rule - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Specialize  the Product Rule below at $\rm \,A = a^n,\,\ B = b^n\,$ and $\rm\,m = a-b$

**Congruence Product Rule** $\rm\quad\ a\equiv b,\ \ and \ \  A\equiv B\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{aA\equiv bB}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: a\!-\!b,\ A\!-\!B\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ \underbrace{(a\!-\!b)\ A + b\ (A\!-\!B)\ =\ \color{#c00}{aA - bB}} $
**Remark** $\ $ The above is precisely the same equation as in Hagen's answer.